# What's the keyframes on action level in Dope Sheet? And how to deselect them?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

My dope sheet looks like this:

[image]

What I don't get is why "Action" has its own keyframes?

[image]

And even more weirdly, I can't deselect them by `Select -> None`. These keyframes are always selected.

Comment: It's the dope sheet, so that serves as an overview of all of the keyframes of any f-curve that  are part of the action.  Do you have any keyframes selected in any of the lines that are part of the action?

Comment: I've found the answer... I have selected some hidden IK bones' keyframes. It turns out one can't deselect what's hidden, even with `Select -> None`. There is a button on Dope Sheet's header to show hidden things.